# Finding Resolvant of a Matrix with given eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

The eigenvalues of a $3\times 3$ matrix $M$ are $0,i\alpha$ and $-i\alpha$, where $\alpha >0$.

Show that
$$(zI-M)^{-1}=\frac{1}{z}M+\frac{z}{z^2+\alpha^2}M+\frac{1}{z^2+\alpha^2}M^2$$

---

I'm trying this way: In the eigenbasis, The matrix $M$ look like
$$M=\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0\\
0&i\alpha&0\\
0&0&-i\alpha
\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow zI-M=\begin{pmatrix}
z&0&0\\
0&z-i\alpha&0\\
0&0&z+i\alpha
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$\text{adj}(zI-M)=\begin{pmatrix}
z^2+\alpha^2&0&0\\
0&z(z+i\alpha)&0\\
0&0&z(z-i\alpha)
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$R(z;M)=\frac{\text{adj}(zI-M)}{p(z)}=\frac{1}{z(z^2+\alpha^2)}\begin{pmatrix}
z^2+\alpha^2&0&0\\
0&z(z+i\alpha)&0\\
0&0&z(z-i\alpha)
\end{pmatrix}$$
The right hand side of the proof can be explicitly found
$$\frac{1}{z}\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0\\
0&i\alpha&0\\
0&0&-i\alpha
\end{pmatrix}+\frac{z}{z^2+\alpha^2}\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0\\
0&i\alpha&0\\
0&0&-i\alpha
\end{pmatrix}+\frac{1}{z^2+\alpha^2}\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0\\
0&-\alpha^2&0\\
0&0&-\alpha^2
\end{pmatrix}$$
As you can see the first coefficient in here is zero but It's not the same that we get.  I don't get where this goes wrong. Can anyone help me with this.

---

Edit:

On asking, it's turn out there is a typo it should be $I/z$ instead of $M/z$. But setting this apart. I have another problem:

$$\text{det}(zI-M)=z(z^2+\alpha^2)\rightarrow \text{det}(zI-M)^{-1}=\frac{1}{z(z^2+\alpha^2)}$$
But from my calculation
$$\text{det} R(z;M)=z(z^2+\alpha^2)
$$
What's wrong with my calculations?
It's different from what You get just by squaring $M$. What's wrong here?

Comment: $\det (c A) = c^n \det (A)$ where $c$ is scalar, $A$ is $n\times n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum polynomial for $M$ is
$$
   m(z)=z(z-i\alpha)(z+i\alpha)=z(z^2+\alpha^2)=z^3+\alpha^2 z.
$$
From this you can determine the resolvent:
\begin{align}
     m(z)I&=m(z)I-m(M) \\
        &=z^3I+\alpha^2 zI-M^3-\alpha^2 M \\
        &=(z^3I-M^3)+\alpha^2(zI-M) \\
        &=(zI-M)(z^2I+zM+M^2)+\alpha^2(zI-M) \\
        &=(zI-M)((z^2+\alpha^2)I+zM+M^2).
\end{align}
Therefore, $(zI-M)^{-1}$ exists whenever $m(z)\ne 0$, and equals
\begin{align}
        (zI-M)^{-1}&=\frac{1}{m(z)}((z^2+\alpha^2)I+zM+M^2).
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

The identity can not be true. Because the determinant of the left hand side is non zero and the determinant of the right hand side is zero.

Comment: Please find edit.